# AngularJS Pass json data to mvc controller in the form of list

Tags: jquery, angularjs, asp.net-mvc-5

I need to pass json in the form of List to controller in Angular JS Post.

I have tried to send data in form of Json to get it as list in the MVC controller. But when I did it , I get only row count at MVC Controller. The variables in the list are null

AngularJS Controller

```
$scope.SaveTaxRange = function (){
    var formdata = $("#frmTaxSetup").serializeArray();
    var uniqueKey = { name: "AngularJS", value: "SaveTaxRange" };
    formdata.push(uniqueKey);
    var tableData = [];

    try {
        $('#tablTaxRange tbody tr').each(function (index, element) {
            //tableData = {};
            tableData.push({
                Min_amt: $(this).find('th:eq(0) input').val(),
                Max_amt: $(this).find('th:eq(1) input').val(),
                Tax_percent: $(this).find('th:eq(2) input').val(),
                Tax_type: $(this).find('th:eq(3) input').val(),

            });
            tableData.push({
                Min_amt: $(this).find('th:eq(0) input').val(),
                Max_amt: $(this).find('th:eq(1) input').val(),
                Tax_percent: $(this).find('th:eq(2) input').val(),
                Tax_type: $(this).find('th:eq(3) input').val(),

            });
        });

    } catch (e) { alert(e); }

    uniqueKey = { name: "lstTaxRangeSave", value: tableData };
    formdata.push(uniqueKey);
    var data = {};           

    $(formdata).each(function (index, obj) {
        data[obj.name] = obj.value;
    });
    $http({
            url: "/PayModule/Pay_mas_taxsetup",
            method: "Post",
            data: { "model": data }
    }).then(function(response){});
};
```

MVC Model

```
public class TaxSetupMaster
{
    public class TaxRange
    {
        public string Min_amt;
        public string Max_amt;
        public string Tax_percent;
        public string Tax_type;
        public string add;
    }
    public List<TaxRange> lstTaxRangeSave { get; set; }
}
```

MVC Controller

```
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Get | HttpVerbs.Post)]
    public ActionResult Pay_mas_taxsetup( TaxSetupMaster model)
    {
        var a = model.lstTaxRangeSave ;//Here it shows rowcount 2 but the variables are null. Is it feasible to get the data from html? 
    }
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: What is 'data' here: { "model": data }? You're creating a 'tableData' array. Aside from that, you should really be using ng-model for your inputs.

Comment: @ndoes really sorry I have updated my code Please check

Comment: @ndoes does ng-model post full table as list to mvc controller?

Comment: Please do some basic debugging. Is the AngularJS controller creating the correct data for the XHR? Which variable fails to be correct? At which line in the code are unexpected values created?

Comment: If written correctly the [ng-model](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngModel#overview) directive can populate complex JavaScript data structures such as arrays of objects. This provides the additional benefit of AngularJS real-time form validation. This provides a better user experience than server-side validation alone because the user gets instant feedback on how to correct the error. For more information see [AngularJS Developer Guide - Forms](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/forms).

Comment: The [tag:model-view-controller] tag is not appropriate for this question. For Microsoft ASP.NET MVC, please use [tag:asp.net-mvc] or [tag:asp.net-core-mvc] tag instead. For Spring MVC, please use [tag:spring-mvc] tag instead.

Comment: @georgeawg sorry for the wrong tag. In mvc controller the list variable lstTaxRangeSave is showing 2 number of rows but the inner variables are showing null. I passed the same variable names correctly in angular js json

Comment: Can you post the data in the XHR request so we can see what it looks like?

Comment: @Rob Sorry I forgot to put getter setter Now I am getting the values in MV Controller Thanks mate This is my XHR
AngularJS: "SaveTaxRange"
lstTaxRangeSave: Array(2)
0:
Max_amt: "2"
Min_amt: "1"
Tax_percent: "3"
Tax_type: "4"
add1: ""
__proto__: Object
1:
Max_amt: "2"
Min_amt: "1"
Tax_percent: "3"
Tax_type: "4"
add1: ""
__proto__: Object
length: 2
__proto__: Array(0)
tblTaxSetup_length: "25"
__proto__: Object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry my carelessness mates

```
public string Min_amt;
public string Max_amt;
public string Tax_percent;
public string Tax_type;
public string add;
```

yep forgot to add getter and setter

```
public string Min_amt { get; set; }
public string Max_amt { get; set; }
public string Tax_percent { get; set; }
public string Tax_type { get; set; }
public string add { get; set; }
```

Now I am getting the values in the MVC controller
Thanks to everybody for spending your valuable time